# AWS Kinesis "DynamicPartitioning.ActivePartitionsLimitExceeded" Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

**Solution Overview**

An application publish events to a SNS topic, and a Kinesis delivery stream (Firehose) subscribes to the topic, and delivers events directly (no lambda) to a S3 bucket. A glue table is defined on the bucket so that we can query the table using Athena.

**Problem**

In the Firehose delivery stream we configured Dynamic Partitioning (DP) and the key is the primary key of the event record. It was working fine. However when we publish 10K events within less than 10 seconds, we got this `DynamicPartitioning.ActivePartitionsLimitExceeded` error and lots of events were not saved into the bucket with proper prefix.

I tried turning off DP but got "AppendDelimiterToRecordProcessor can only be present when Dynamic Partitioning is enabled" error. After I removed this processor, all the events ended up stored in one file without proper delimieter and Athena could only recognise the first one.

**Question**

I am new to Kinesis, but I thought Kinesis delivery stream + Athena should work together very well. It seems to me that without DP it would not work? I am wondering how people used them before DP was introduced late last year?

[AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/dynamic-partitioning.html) does explain this, but I am just wondering if Kinesis Firehose + Athena will work without DP? We don't really need DP ourselves.

**Update**

My problem is similiar to the following, but I don't get a chance to transform the event when the source of the Firehose is a SNS topic, also I don't want to write a lambda to transform the data yet.

[Kinesis/Firehose/Athena - Creating queryable data from logs](http://thushw.blogspot.com/2019/07/kinesisfirehoseathena-creating.html)

[Firehose to S3 with One Record Per Line](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244858)

Comment: Just came across this, and it appears to be the only question in the universe on the subject, so, thanks... lol. I'm hitting the same problem, although my data does appear to be getting to S3. Were you able to solve it? I'm using both dynamic partitioning and a lambda for timestamp formatting, and am considering ditching the dynamic partitions entirely if that's what it takes to get past this.

Comment: @wkhatch I didn't really solve it but just worked it around by using another field which is much less diverse instead of the primary key therefore even when 10K events are published the partition key values are much less than the limit of 500. In this way everything still works fine. The only shortcoming is that if we could use primary key as the prefix then events of the same record always go under the same folder in S3 and it's easier to locate them manually.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining what causes it. That's exactly what I'm doing,  too; trying to partition by associated devices' events. Apparently, we can request limit increases, but I'm going to simplify as you did. I also stopped using inline parsing completely and did everything in the lambda; same result. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same challenge and the solution to this, should design the number of partitions in such a way it follows the following

partitions * buffer time (secs) <= maximum active partitions